# Adding Custom Fields to User Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using [this tutorial](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-core/add-custom-fields-to-user-in-asp-net-core-identity/) to add a couple fields to the user table. In my code I have the following lines:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .Property(e => e.RegistrationDate);

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .Property(e => e.RegistrationIPAddress);

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .Property(e => e.Banned);
}
```

I have looked up lambda expression which I believe is what this is, but I'm not understanding what these lines do, and why they are required, i.e.:

1. What is the point of the RegistrationDate line and what is it doing?
2. Do I need to add these lines for every new field I add to the user
   table?

This is my first time working with Entity Framework and all of the documents are getting a little confusing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the user table already exists then you can get EF to write all this code for you. Open the package manager console and write something like:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "whatever connection string you are using here" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

EF will generate everything for the DB and wire up all the objects.

Not everything needs an entry in db context - sometimes you can add a simple property to an entity and EF will just pick it up, but generally you'll scaffold an existing db to get a start and then you can either re scaffold it if the db changes (scaffold it to a new dir and use a diff tool if you have modified the classes that were generated) or more typically you use [migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/) to update the db which is a process where you make the model changes in c# side and then tell EF you've changed the model, it diffs your changes compared to an earlier snapshot it took and generates the db commands necessary to alter the db. You can alter the commands it generated and you can tell it to run the changes, either from the command line or from code if you just want a "deploy and forget" approach; EF will change the db as the application starts up